# Unable to attach file with email in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to attach image with email. I tried many way. But I'm failed. No  file attached with email. I also tried embed image but that also not working. Please help me to find out problem.

```
Mail::send('emails.freetrial', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $img =  Freetrialsimage::where('freetrials_id', '=', $data['id']);
        $message->from('hello123@gmail.com');
        $message->to('text123@gmail.com');
        $message->subject('Free Trial');
        foreach ($img as $attach)
      {
          $message->attachData($img->file_path, $img->file_name);;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to attach file by path - use `attach()` method, if you have raw content of the file (binary image data) - then use `attachData()`. In your example it looks like `attach()` is more suitable.

From documentation

> When attaching files to a message, you may also specify the display name and / or MIME type by passing an array as the second argument to the attach method:
>
> `$message->attach($pathToFile, ['as' => $display, 'mime' => $mime]);`

And about attachData() method

> The attachData method may be used to attach a raw string of bytes as an attachment. For example, you might use this method if you have generated a PDF in memory and want to attach it to the e-mail without writing it to disk:
>
> `$message->attachData($pdf, 'invoice.pdf');`